# Loading angular in IE from file system

Tags: angularjs, security, internet-explorer, mark-of-the-web

I have an angular app that has to be loaded from the file system, by IE, and will be shipped to clients (so I can't override security configurations)

The error I am getting has to do with trying to ng-include templates and getting an `Error: Access is denied.` in IE.

Searching the web, I found the perfect solution in the form of Mark of the Web.
I added `<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->` to the second line of my index.html, but that didn't remove the error.

I know another possible solution is to add all my templates as `<script type="text/ng-template">` and load them from the templateCache, but this will be a large app and I don't want to have all my html written in one file.

Is there anything i'm missing? Any possible solution? Why is my MOTW tag not working? Appreciate any idea, i'm desparate!

Thanks,
Uri

Comment: which version of IE you are using?

Comment: IE 9. Also, i'm now exploring the grunt-html2js plugin to compile all my templates to the template cache

Comment: `<!-- saved from url=(0016)http://localhost -->` works for IE8, but IE9 and higher cannot. I also want to resolve this with IE9 and higher.

Comment: And not only for ng-include, also all the templates loading by router and director